# Installing node once only and not each time with Maven build

Tags: maven, gruntjs

I need one help .

I am using grunt for compiling CSS/JS

I have an issue that my node package is getting created with each build and it is taking a lot of space in Jenkins . I am using maven front end plugin for the same .

I want that node package gets only created once initially and not again with each maven build .

```
 <id>grunt</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.26</version>
                        <!-- optional -->
                        <configuration>
                            <workingDirectory>DIR
                            </workingDirectory>
                            <nodeVersion>v4.2.1</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>3.5.1</npmVersion>
                            <installDirectory>node</installDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                      <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>node and npm install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                                    <installDirectory>node</installDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                                    <installDirectory>node</installDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>grunt build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>grunt</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>build</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
```

We are doing a build with maven -P grunt . It is creating and installing node with each maven build .

For having node globally I am trying maven -P grunt -g , but it is not working .

In the GitHub group , I saw people mentioning we can't do with maven frontend plugin , so I tried maven exec plugin .

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>prepare-dist-npm-runtime-dependency</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <executable>node/node</executable>
          <workingDirectory>dist</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
            <argument>../node/npm/cli.js</argument>
            <argument>install</argument>
            <argument>--production</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But I am not able to see it working . Can anyone help how to run maven to get it working for global node installation and not installing node with each build ?

If any other suggestion to have node installed only once and not globally will be grateful .

Comment: I think that because you run maven build using profile all the time, it will generate node as times as you build. I think you should configure your jenkins CI only trigger build when some changes in script. By default, jenkins should run default maven build, not run by profile.

Answer (score 5):

You can't install Node or NPM globally with the `Frontend maven plugin`. If we take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) we'll see that the entire purpose of the plugin is to be able to install Node and NPM in an isolated environment solely for the build and which does not affect the rest of the machine.

> Node/npm will only be "installed" locally to your project. It will not
>   be installed globally on the whole system (and it will not interfere
>   with any Node/npm installations already present.)
>
> Not meant to replace the developer version of Node - frontend
>   developers will still install Node on their laptops, but backend
>   developers can run a clean build without even installing Node on their
>   computer.
>
> Not meant to install Node for production uses. The Node usage is
>   intended as part of a frontend build, running common javascript tasks
>   such as minification, obfuscation, compression, packaging, testing
>   etc.

You can try to run the plugin with two different profiles, one for install and one for day-to-day use after installation. In the below example, you should be able to install Node and NPM by running:

```
mvn clean install -PinstallNode
```

Then every build after:

```
mvn clean install -PnormalBuild
```

Or because `normalBuild` is set to active by default, just:

```
mvn clean install
```

Notice install goals are not in the day-to-day profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>installNode</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.26</version>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>DIR</workingDirectory>
                        <nodeVersion>v4.2.1</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>3.5.1</npmVersion>
                        <installDirectory>node</installDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                  <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>node and npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install</arguments>
                                <installDirectory>node</installDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install</arguments>
                                <installDirectory>node</installDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>grunt build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>grunt</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>normalBuild</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.26</version>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>DIR</workingDirectory>
                        <nodeVersion>v4.2.1</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>3.5.1</npmVersion>
                        <installDirectory>node</installDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>grunt build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>grunt</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: For example, in one project I have 3 main profiles: one that does a full build in which it gets all NPM and Bower dependencies, builds our client-side AMD and SASS, and builds the jars; another just builds the client-side assets and jars without getting the dependencies; and the final only builds the Java bundles. That way in day-to-day Java development, I don't need to continually run Bower or Grunt. When I do update the JS or CSS, I can run the profile that will run Bower and Grunt. I can run the full build only when I need to pull in the dependencies and don't slow myself down otherwise.

Comment: Thanks your answer was exactly what I was looking for to solve my specific problem.